# Vulcanizing cement question?

Tags: tire

I was sent vulcanizing cement instead of rubber glue. I need a strong glue for LED strip lights. Everywhere I go looking for vulcanizing cement answers leads to tires, but not what all else it can be used for. Can I use vulcanizing cement on LED strip lights?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the use of glue unconnected to cycles or cycling.

Comment: Are your LEDs on some kind of rubber strip like a tyre's inner tube?  Please tell us how this is related to rubber and/or bicycles.

Answer (score 3):

Vulcanization is used to describe the chemical process of hardening rubber. Essentially, Vulcanizing rubber cement is the same thing as rubber glue, but contains accelerators to speed up the drying process, which is why it's handy for patching tires, since you want a fast drying adhesive for patches.

There shouldn't be any issue using it to adhere LED strip lights, just avoid covering the LEDs themselves with the cement as it'll cause them to heat up, and heat is what kills LEDs. Also avoid covering the solder patches with cement if you plan on using them down the line. Otherwise, the product is fairly inert and won't damage your LEDs.